# Issue with CoreData light migration.

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, appdelegate

I needed to change my `xcdatamodeld` so I followed this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration).

I created another .mom file and added one attribute to one of the previous entities. Then I set this in my `AppDelegate`.

```
NSDictionary *options = @{
                              NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                              NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES
                              };

    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) ...
```

I thought it was OK but when I try to interact with core data my app crashes with this error.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores.  It cannot perform a save operation.'
```

What did i miss?

Comment: Do you get an `error` during `addPersistentStoreWithType`? What is it?

Comment: what you mean by "during creation"? The error comes whenever i try to invoke `[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];`

Comment: actually i just added these lines of code, before the migration the core data worked well, i supposed the persistentStoreCoordinator should have worked like before.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve, actually i needed to update also the persistentStoreCoordinator i created to handle the database on iCloud with the `NSDictionary` i called `options`.